# IBM Worklight 6.1 Developer edition Download Link

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to download the IBM Worklight 6.1 from market place or google but i can't see any results for same, Can any one please share a link for IBM WL 6.1 and also how to upgrade the fix pack to 6.1.0.1. Also i am looking for developers edition. Since the 6.2 is released i can only see 6.2 links and not 6.1

Can any one please suggest what can be done. Appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks
Deepesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Worklight Developer Edition, only the latest released version (which is 6.2, at this moment) is available from the Eclipse Marketplace as an Eclipse update site.  If you really want 6.1.0.1 Developer Edition, you can download it as an Eclipse installation archive here:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/iws_update_site_wde.6.1.0.2.zip

The prior 6.1 Developer Edition version (before Fix Pack 1) is not available for download any longer.

Comment: Great, is this a fix pack or entire package which can be installed in eclipse as a plugin, please confirm.

Comment: The ZIP file at the link above is an entire installation repository.  Add it to your Eclipse by using "Help -> Install New Software... -> Add...", and select the "Archive..." button to add the ZIP archive.  Once you've done that, you can choose this repository in the "Work with:" dropdown and select the Worklight components to be installed.

Comment: Other Versions are also available :
1)5.0.6.2 : http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.5.0.6.2.zip

2) 6.0.0.2 : http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.0.0.2.zip