# IBM Worklight - How to switch back to version 6.1 from 6.2 for MaC OS?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have downloaded 6.2.0 Worklight version i.e. latest one from market place for developing iOS app. But now I came to know that my server runs on 6.1.0 version on Windows 7 machine and furthur deployment of war would be on 6.1.0 only.

Due to this, I am getting "Unresponsive host". I want to switch back to 6.1.0 version again and need zip file of WK 6.1.0 for MAC OS only. please help me out by providing link for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be to search before asking a question... :)

- [IBM Worklight - Where to find previous releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493510/ibm-worklight-where-to-find-previous-releases)
- [IBM Worklight 6.1 Developer edition Download Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747311/ibm-worklight-6-1-developer-edition-download)

Note that if you are an IBM customer or business partner, you should use the latest available from IBM Fix Center, for both your server and studio installations.

Comment: I was already open to down vote. MY TM's has messed up things, since tomorrow is delivery i didn't has any option unless to ask question here. Already wrote Sorry in advance. :P. well thanks dude.