# IBM Worklight (6.1.0.2) Developer Edition - Installation on Eclipse Juno SR2- Missing requirement org.apache.commons.collections

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I've trying to install IBM Worklight (6.1.0.2) Developer Edition plugin on Eclipse Juno SR2.
Worklight Downloaded from provided link.
[IBM Worklight 6.1 Developer edition Download Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747311/ibm-worklight-6-1-developer-edition-download-link).
But once I install, the error appears as follow.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: IBM Dojo Mobile Tools
>   6.1.0.02-20151226-1310 (com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.02-20151226-1310)   Missing requirement: IBM Worklight Studio (Developer Edition) 6.1.0.02-20151226-1310
>   (com.worklight.studio.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.02-20151226-1310)
>   requires 'org.apache.commons.collections [3.2.1]' but it could not be
>   found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: IBM Dojo Mobile Tools 6.1.0.02-20151226-1310 (com.ibm.imp.dojo.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.02-20151226-1310)
>       To: com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.02-20151226-1310 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.02-20151226-1310)
>       To: com.worklight.studio.feature.feature.group 6.1.0

Could anyone please advice me? 
Developer edition (6.1.0.2) is the only one I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was tested with the build: Worklight-plugin.6.1.0.02-20151228-1319 and found to be working. You can download the .zip file from the IBM FTP site, here: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/iws_update_site_wde.6.1.0.2.zip